# What is the parenthetical number indicative of?

Tags: support, flagging, flag-history

This seems to only show up on spam flags that are pending review.  What does the parenthetical number next to the offending post's title indicate?

[image: giant flag parentheses picture]

Comment: FWIW, these flags have been now been reviewed and the parenthetical number remains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the number of answers the flagged question got.